# Variable naming conventions for function variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, standards, organization

beginner here. I'm writing a script that has a few related functions and am wondering what the standards are for naming the variables within my functions. For example if I have `function_1` and `function_2` that both a take some sort of file, is it acceptable to name both variables `file`? I know it will work, but is that horrible coding practice or is it alright to do?

```
def function_1(file):
    # Do something
    return file

def function_2(file):
    # Do something
    return file

def main():
    file_1 = function_1(file)
    file_2 = function_2(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the two are parameters within the scope of two different functions, it is completely fine to name them the same. However, since `file` is a builtin in Python, I would suggest to name it differently or to add an underscore at the end of the name.